# Is the following verse: “he found you lost and guided you” 93:8 addressed only to the prophet saw or for all Muslims?

Tags: quran, tafseer, prophet-muhammad

I recently had a discussion with a close relative and he believes that this verse is only applicable for the prophet saw whereas I believe that this addresses all the Muslims . Could anyone confirm which is true ?